# segmentation fault when printing a list of values from the memory

Tags: memory, printing, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make a small application that prints the content of a number of consecutive memory locations. As an indication of where the program is in the memory, I am printing the memory location of the main function and of a dummy variable.

In a first column, I want to print the address. In a second column, I want the contents of this address and the content of the 9 addresses behind it. In a third column, I want to print the byte value as a char, if it is printable. If it is not printable, I want to print a dot. In the rows under the first, I do exactly the same.

At startup, a number of values to print can be entered. If a positive value is entered, the addresses will increment, if a negative value is entered, the addresses will decrement.

To quickly see where I want to get to, you could run the code and enter for example 20 bytes to dump and use the address of the dummy as a starting address.

So far, my code only works for positive values. When I enter a negative number, I get a segmentation fault, but I can't figure out why. I tried to find the error in Valgrind, without success.

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_BYTES 10

void showAddresses(void);
void printMemory(void);
void getDumpSize(void);

char* dummy;                // dummy is een pointer naar een int
signed int dumpSize;            // how many bytes have to be dumped?
signed int upDown;          // do I need to go up or down?


int main(void)
{
    dummy = (char *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char));// memory allocation
    showAddresses();    // prints the main function address and a variable address
    getDumpSize();  //      
    printMemory();  //
    free(dummy);        // free memory
    return 0;       // end the main function
}

void showAddresses(void)
{
    printf("Main function address is %p \n", main); 
    printf("Dummy variable address is %p \n",(void*)dummy);
}

void getDumpSize(void)
{
    printf("Enter number of bytes to dump <negative or positive>:");
    scanf("%d",&dumpSize);
    if(dumpSize<0)
    {
        upDown = -1;        // count down
        printf("upDown was set to -1\n");
    }
    else
    {
        upDown = 1;         // count up
        printf("upDown was set to +1\n");
    }
}

void printMemory(void)
{
    int input;
    printf("Enter the address:");
    scanf("%x", &input);                // enter the input
    printf("Address \tBytes \t\t\t\tChars \n"); // print the table header
    printf("--------- \t----------------------------- \t---------- ");
    int i;
    unsigned char* address;         // 
    for(i=0;i<abs(dumpSize);i++)
    {
        address = (unsigned char*) (input+(i*upDown));  // make the address to print
        if( (i%NUMBER_OF_BYTES) == 0)   // show the address every 'i*NUMBER_OF_BYTES' times
        {
            printf("\n%p \t", (void*) address); 
        }

        printf("%02x ", *address);  // print as a 2 number hex and use zero padding if needed


        if( (i%NUMBER_OF_BYTES) == (NUMBER_OF_BYTES-1) )// print the char list for every value (if printable)
        {
            printf("\t");
            int j;
            for(j=(NUMBER_OF_BYTES-1);j>=0;j--)
            {
                address = (unsigned char*) (input+(i*upDown)-j); 
                if(isprint(*address)==0)// print a dot if the byte value is not printable
                {
                    printf(".");
                }
                else
                {
                     printf("%c",*address); // print the byte value as a char, if printable
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your segmentation fault is likely coming from attempting to access memory outside of your program's scope.  The address in "dummy" is the first malloc from your program, so it represents (possibly) the first "area" of memory available to your program.  Going up from there might be keeping you in program space (hence the lack of seg fault), but going backward might be driving you into a restricted memory area.  Out of curiosity: what is the memory address returned for your "dummy" malloc?  Is the number even large enough to go backward without going negative?  (I'm wondering if your program sees the true system memory map or a paged map that is already sand-boxed for programs.)

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply! I think that was indeed what went wrong. Someone told me today that because the dummy is a global variable, it is close to restricted memory. This appeared to be just one of the reasons for the segmentation fault. I also tried this code on another system, and noticed that it didn't work. I think I should use 'long int input' instead of 'int input' since on some systems the size of an int is not sufficient for some memory addresses.